# Hasicorp Vault TLS kubernetes certificates setup

Tags: node.js, azure, ssl, kubernetes

I have a 3 node Vault cluster with a 3 node Consul backend running in a AKS V1.19.3 cluster. There are no services exposing this cluster to the outside world as I have no need for access outside this cluster, hence I have a single ClusterIP Service named vault in namespace vault defined. I have no problem to port-forward to this service and creating all my secret, transit, policies and appRole definitions in the cluster but when I try to connect to the cluster from my backend service, with approlelogin, I am getting the following error

```
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179653680Z error loging in approle RequestError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179668980Z     at new RequestError (/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179672780Z     at Request.plumbing.callback (/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179676280Z     at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179680980Z     at self.callback (/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179684380Z     at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179687480Z     at Request.onRequestError (/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179690680Z     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179693880Z     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179697380Z     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179700280Z     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179703280Z     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179706280Z     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179709380Z   cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179712380Z       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1498:34)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179715380Z       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179729980Z       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:933:8)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179734180Z       at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:707:12)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179737280Z       at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:123:14) {
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179740280Z     code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179743280Z   },
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179746380Z   error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179749380Z       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1498:34)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179752380Z       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179755280Z       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:933:8)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179758380Z       at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:707:12)
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179761480Z       at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:123:14) {
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179766280Z     code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179769380Z   },
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179772480Z   options: {
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179775380Z     json: {
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179778280Z       role_id: '7f232329-51d4-eafc-b968-6a44a2506e74',
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179781280Z       secret_id: '17fd2652-74b0-eb74-db58-44f42e9cf122'
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179813580Z     },
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179818180Z     resolveWithFullResponse: true,
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179821180Z     simple: false,
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179824180Z     strictSSL: true,
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179827180Z     method: 'POST',
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179830180Z     path: '/auth/approle/login',
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179833280Z     headers: {},
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179836280Z     uri: 'https://vault.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/auth/approle/login',
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179839480Z     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179843280Z     transform: undefined,
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179846380Z     transform2xxOnly: false
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179849380Z   },
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179852380Z   response: undefined
2020-11-18T05:07:17.179855380Z }
```

I am assuming this is a problem with my ca.cert, used to sign my self signed certificates, not being recognised.
I have this code running locally on my mac in a rancher k3s cluster but I used the Kubernetes CSR to sign my certs (signer: kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving) and I used the ca for this signing authority. I would prefer to go this method and have kubernetes manage the certificate renewals but I dont know where to get this CA cert from in Azure (or whether this is a good practice anyway).
Any help to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.